# background images in area between header and footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am making a page whose layout is divided into 3 sections : Header, main body, and footer. I want a background image in my main body. Now when i try to do that, i am experiencing a problem. The image is not covering the complete area. It leaves some area at the bottom. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QcUfm/) for proper explanation.

Here is what i have done so far:

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gehri Route: Login, Signup</title>
    </head>
    <body>
           <div class='headercontainer'>
                      <div class='header'>
                          header
                      </div>
            </div>
            <div class='mainbodycontainer'>
                     </div>
            <div class = 'footercontainer'>

                         <div class='footer'>
                               footer
                        </div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.headercontainer
{
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
  min-width: 999px;
  height:60px;
  border:1px solid #666;
  left: 0;
}

.mainbodycontainer
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
  min-width: 999px;
  padding: 80px 0;
        background: url("http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/107/cache/california-profile_10719_600x450.jpg?01AD=3Eg20HvemHwApI8-INwZvViX_nk9hW8HJTh_oBQchW4pJwAzYLvxz9w&01RI=A8733DF327AC3E9&01NA=na") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


.footercontainer
{
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
  width: 100%;
  height:82px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  left:0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.header
{
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 999px;
}



.mainbody
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 999px;
}
```

Also please help me to make this responsive design.

Comment: perhaps you want to replace your oldsql `div`s with some new fancy html5 elements like `<header>` or `<footer>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to force a height to the body and html tag of 100%. If there is no content the background won't appear because the height of the element (.mainbodycontainer) is 0. In your case it was 80px because you applied padding.

check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/olwez/ncLZN/

I added a height to the body and html tags of 100% and a minimum height of 100% to the .mainbodycontainer div. That way you don't have to manually set the heights or have content within the .mainbodycontainer for the image to behave as you wish.

I just threw in an overflow: hidden; on the body tag so that scrolling is gone.

Here is the full css.

```
html { height: 100% }
body
{
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.headercontainer
{
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
  min-width: 999px;
  height:60px;
  border:1px solid #666;
  left: 0;
}

.mainbodycontainer
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
  min-width: 999px;
  min-height: 100%;
        background: url("http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/107/cache/california-profile_10719_600x450.jpg?01AD=3Eg20HvemHwApI8-INwZvViX_nk9hW8HJTh_oBQchW4pJwAzYLvxz9w&01RI=A8733DF327AC3E9&01NA=na") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


.footercontainer
{
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
  width: 100%;
  height:82px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  left:0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.header
{
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 999px;
}



.mainbody
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 999px;
}
```

Comment: +1 for finding the overflow thing. I was searching the reason for scrolling.

Comment: I am tried this on my ipad, but its giving me vertically scrolling, which i dont want. How to remove vertical scroll ?

Comment: You have a min-width set and a bunch of other widths with defined values such as 999px. It could be flipping it to landscape could be a problem. Try changing those to %100 or % in general. Hard for me to test right now.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your style:

```
    width:600px;
    height:450px;


.mainbodycontainer
 {
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
   min-width: 999px;
   padding: 80px 0;
    background: url("http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/107/cache/california-profile_10719_600x450.jpg?01AD=3Eg20HvemHwApI8-INwZvViX_nk9hW8HJTh_oBQchW4pJwAzYLvxz9w&01RI=A8733DF327AC3E9&01NA=na") no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   width:600px;
   height:450px;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/QcUfm/9/

Comment: fixing a hight is not a good idea, if he wants to add more stuff, longer than 450px, it won't work. using % is better as @olwez said.

Answer (score 0):

A background image will only show as much is revealed either by the content or a height. If your div doesn't have enough content to force the parent element big enough, you won't see it all. Also, if you are using any type of positioning like fixed, absolute or even relative and moving it, that can affect it also. I didn't look at the fiddle but those are some common issues.